# What is the recommended way to encrypt in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, security, cryptography, utl-file

I need some help from Oracle/Security experts.

I'm going to make functions for encryption/decryption in our Oracle DB. I intend to use `dbms_crypto` with `AES256`. I understand that I should store the key file in the O/S and read it using `utl_file`.

Is this a good idea? Are there any problems with this approach? E.g. Can utl_file have problems if the key file is read concurrently by 10 callers of the function? Is anything else recommended instead?

I'm sure that this is a very common thing. Does anyone know where I can find a good sample that does this?

Since this is security-related, I would prefer to follow some standard that others are following.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Oracle Advanced Security in your Oracle Database Enterprise Edition, you already have transparent data encryption (TDE) of data stored in the database.Take a look:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14268/asotrans.htm

You can check out also this link:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/TransparentDataEncryption_10gR2.php

Summarizing the last page:

- Setup: Creating a database file and user.

  CONN sys/password AS SYSDBA

  CREATE TABLESPACE tde_test
    DATAFILE '/u01/oradata/DB10G/tde_test.dbf' SIZE 128K
    AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 64K;

  CREATE USER test IDENTIFIED BY test DEFAULT TABLESPACE tde_test;
  ALTER USER test QUOTA UNLIMITED ON tde_test;
  GRANT CONNECT TO test;
  GRANT CREATE TABLE TO test;
- Encrypted Data: How to create a encrypted Column.You must create a wallet to hold the encryption key.Add the following entry into the sqlnet.ora file on the server and make sure the specified directory has been created.

  ENCRYPTION_WALLET_LOCATION=
    (SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=
      (DIRECTORY=/u01/app/oracle/admin/DB10G/encryption_wallet/)))

You must create and opne the wallet:

```
CONN sys/password AS SYSDBA
ALTER SYSTEM SET ENCRYPTION KEY AUTHENTICATED BY "myPassword";
```

Then you can create your tables with the desired columns encrypted or not:

```
CREATE TABLE tde_test (
  id    NUMBER(10),
  data  VARCHAR2(50) ENCRYPT
)
TABLESPACE tde_test;
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: +1 Thank you. That was useful information, however, what I need is a pair of encryption/decryption functions. I must be able to encrypt/decrypt on the fly. The data does not necessarily reside in a table.

Comment: You're welcome ;)... mmm, and how about DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT? It contain functions to encrypt/decrypt data using either the Data Encryption Standard (DES) or the Triple DES algorithms.

Comment: From what I understand, DBMS_CRYPTO is recommended. DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT is for older DBs. Moreover, I need to protect the key by storing it in the O/S.

Comment: @Zesty,yes, you're right. IN this url http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/apdvncrp.htm you can find some example using DBMS_CRYPTO and your different options to storing the Keys (in your OS, in the database, etc..)